# Wordpress category menu returns 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I connected a post category to a menu, so when I click that menu, the posts in the category are displayed.

Even though my category has 41 posts, always I clicked the '<-older posts' button, it returns 404 error. For example, if I set 5 posts to be displayed, only recent 5 posts are displayed and it returns 404 errors when I clicked the '<- older posts' button. If I set 1 post, I cannot see the second recentest post. It is very weird. :(

I cannot find a solution for this problem. Is there any possible solution or hint?

Thanks, in advance.

PS.
I put some pictures to help you understand.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your permalink structure?

Comment: @bodi0 Thank you for your answer. It is actually permalink problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. I put my own answer for future people who suffer similar problem.

I just changed my permalink option in Setting panel. I guess there are some conflict in permalink setting, so after I changed my permalink setting, WordPress set all links of posts again. It solved my problem.